# trying to created a multi-client chatroom, were a user types in something and it appears on all the clients screens

Tags: python, python-3.x

after the second message to be sent in general it shows the error, my guess is that its either deleting the sockets or somehow they stop being such. which is weird
`Traceback (most recent call last): File "direcory\socket_test_server.py", line 26, in <module> i.sendall(data) OSError: [WinError 10038] An operation was attempted on something that is not a socket`

this here is my code:

```
import socket
import threading

HOST = "192.168.81.192"
PORT = 2222

clients = set()
client_lick = threading.Lock()

while True:
    s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    s.bind((HOST, PORT))
    s.listen()
    conn, addr = s.accept()
    with conn:
        print(f"Connected by {addr}")
        with client_lick:
            clients.add(conn)
        while True:
            data = conn.recv(1000000)
            if not data:
                break
            else:
                with client_lick:
                    for i in clients:
                        i.sendall(data)
```

i tried making a multi-client chatroom. where the address of each client is stored and when a message by any of them is sent, said message will be displayed on all the clients screens. the expectation was that after refreshing said screens the messages would be displayed